# Feeds are real, not fiction! (aka Feeds system account got wrong avatar)

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat, profile-picture

Our beloved [Feeds](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-2) chat account suddenly got a new avatar:

> [image]

The source is: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/scifi/img/icon-48.png?v=73abb3 and happens to be the icon for [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

While bit funny and refreshing, can we please have the [good old RSS icon](http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/Img/feed-icon32.png) back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what happened there.

Old icon reinstated.

Comment: Thanks, on behalf of the Feeds lovers! :-)

Comment: @Sha what about Feeds loathers?